# How can you add IP restrictions to your rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to add IP restrictions to the rails app. Some type of rack middleware so only the set list of IPs can access the rails app for security reasons?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a routing constraint as described here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `before_filter` in the application controller and check the request IP,and redirect it to a no-access page.

```
if request.remote_ip !~ /^XXX\.YYY\.ZZZ\./
  redirect_to no_access_url
  return false
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't rack middleware be used for this?

Comment: I dont know how to use Rack for this...I think this can also be done on web server configuration(Apache or Nginx), but not sure of that too :(

Comment: Note: all you can really do is check remote_ip, but any check of remote_ip will also be misled or possibly defeated by users going through a proxy.