# How to set multi IPs constraints on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip

Now in my routes.rb

```
constraints(:ip => Settings.ip.allow) do
  post '/somecontroller/callback', to: 'somecontroller#callback' , as: 'somecontroller_callback'
end
```

In my settings.yml

```
ip:
  allow: '127.0.0.1'
```

It's ok.

But when I added multi IPs like:

```
ip:
  allow: '/127.0.0.1|127.0.0.2/'
```

It doesn't work.Why and how to do by this method?

Comment: fyi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101629/how-can-you-add-ip-restrictions-to-your-rails-app , and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints , http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints

Comment: Thank you.I want to know if there is a method like using settings.yml above?

Comment: check this out http://www.slideshare.net/silviorelli/rails-routes-off-the-tracks slide 10, is this +- wat you looking for

Comment: wat about https://dev.tscolari.me/2012/09/19/complex-constraints-for-rails-routes/ , could this constraints(:ip => Settings.ip.allow) do ... not b changed to constraints(Settings.ip.allow) do ... , and or something like .. allow: '/127.0.0.1|127.0.0.2/' shouldnt it b allow: ["127.0.0.1","127.0.0.2"] ... idea from http://sriram-iyengar.blogspot.com/2011/09/rails-3-reading-arrays-array-of-hashes.html

Comment: In routes.rb:`constraints(:ip => %r{#{Settings.ip.allow}}) do`.In settings.yml:`allow: '127.0.0.1|127.0.0.2'`.